# Docker compose/swarm 3: docker file path , build, container name, links, migration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have project with docker-compose file and want to migrate to V3, but when deploy with

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml vertx
```

It does not understand build path, links, container names...

My file  locate d here
https://github.com/armdev/vertx-spring/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  eureka-node:
    image: eureka-node
    build: ./eureka-node
    container_name: eureka-node
    ports:
      - '8761:8761'
    networks:
      - vertx-network
  postgres-node:
    image: postgres-node
    build: ./postgres-node
    container_name: postgres-node
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - vertx-network
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: socnet
      POSTGRES_DB: socnet
  vertx-node:
    image: vertx-node
    build: ./vertx-node
    container_name: vertx-node
    links:
      - postgres-node
      - eureka-node
    ports:
      - '8585:8585'
    networks:
      - vertx-network
networks:
  vertx-network:
    driver: overlay
```

when I run docker-compose up, it is working, but with
stack deploy not.

How to define path for docker file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swarm mode "docker service" interface has a few fundamental differences in how it manages containers. You are no longer directly running containers like with "docker run", and it is assumed that you will be doing this in a distributed environment more often than not.

I'll break down the answer by these specific things you listed.

> It does not understand build path, links, container names...

### Links

The link option has been deprecated for quite some time in favor of the network service discovery feature introduced alongside the "docker network" feature. You no longer need to specify specific links to/from containers. Instead, you simply need to ensure that all containers are on the same network and then they can discovery eachother by the container name or "network alias"

`docker-compose` will put all your containers into the same network by default, and it sets up the compose service name as an alias. That means if you have a service called 'postgres-node', you can reach it via dns by the name 'postgres-node'.

### Container Names

The "docker service" interface allows you to declare a desired state. "I want *x* number of identical services". Since the interface must support *x* number of instances of a service, it doesn't allow you to choose the specific container name. Instead, you get to choose the service name. In the case of 'docker stack deploy', the service name defined under the services key in your docker-compose.yml file will be used, but it will also prepend the stack name to the service name.

In most cases, I would argue that overriding the container name in a docker-compose.yml file is unnecessary, even when using regular containers via `docker-compose up`.

If you need a different name for network service discovery purposes, add a different alias or use the service name alias that you get when using `docker-compose` or `docker stack deploy`.

### build path

Because swarm mode was built to be a distributed system, building an image in place locally isn't something that "docker stack deploy" was meant to do. Instead, you should build and push your image to a registry that all nodes in your cluster can access.

In the case where you are using a single node swarm "cluster", you should be able to use the `docker-compose build` option to get the images built locally, and then use `docker stack deploy`.

Answer (score 3):

`docker stack deploy` works only on images, not on builds.

This means that you will have to push your images  to an image registry (created with the build process), later `docker stack deploy` will download the images and execute them.

[here](https://www.goetas.com/blog/how-do-i-deploy-my-symfony-api-part-5-conclusion/) you have an example of how was it done for a php application.
You have to pay attention to the parts 1, 3 and 4.
The articles are about php, but can easily be applied to any other language.